# Select returns results from last day, on mondays doesn´t return friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have a select that returns a result from the previous day. everything is ok but, come to monday, it returns the result from sunday, and i need it to return the previous friday results instead.

i tried to go back 3 days when the datetime is monday, but it's not working.

this is where I started

```
SELECT no, nome, obrano, datafinal  
    FROM bo
    WHERE nmdos LIKE '%preço%'
    AND datafinal = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

this is where i'm at

```
SELECT no, nome, obrano, datafinal  
    FROM bo
    WHERE nmdos LIKE '%preço%'
    AND datafinal = DATEADD(day, - case convert (datetime, 'Dy') when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

i just get conversion errors all over, don't get why

Comment: `CONVERT(datetime, 'Dy')`? What date are you expecting the **literal string** `'dy'`  to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `SELECT convert (datetime, 'Dy')`. This already throws an error:

> ```
> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
> ```

Avoid doing date checks with names (like `Monday`, `March`, `Jan`, etc.), this can change depending on the configured language. The correct form you are searching (I think) is

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) -- Returns 'Tuesday'
```

---

A better solution is to set `DATEFIRST` to a known value (for the `DATEPART WEEKDAY`) and do the comparison with the day number. You can use a `CASE` to change the `-1` to `-3`:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

SELECT 
    no, 
    nome, 
    obrano, 
    datafinal  
FROM 
    bo
WHERE 
    nmdos LIKE '%preço%' AND 
    datafinal = DATEADD(
        DAY,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 1 -- If today is monday
            THEN -3 ELSE -1 END
        CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Also it's recommended to write the full datepart keyword so it doesn't bring confusion (write `WEEKDAY` instead of `DW`, `MONTH` instead of `M`, etc.). You can't escape from masks such as `yyyy-MM-dd` though.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```
case convert(datetime, 'Dy') when 'Mon'
```

You are converting the string `'Dy'` to a date time and then comparing that to a string which is not a datetime.

That is not how convert works.  I think you want:

```
case datename('Dy', getdate()) when 'Monday' . . .
```